# ScrollView with paging iphone sdk

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

in the main view controller i have a scrollview and paging control.

i have added another viewcontroller's view as a page of paging control in scrollview.

now i have 9 buttons on that view controller's view which is inside scroll view.

now when i click on the buton i wants that main view controller's view should be pushed to another view controller.

but not getting how it can be done as the buttons are in view which is in the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user interface element created in interface builder seems not to be doing what you told it to do, you should verify that:

- you saved your changes to the nib in IB
- that you correctly declared your ivars/properties as IBOutlet and connected your outlets in IB
- that there are no views hijacking your events.

If the buttons in your view inside the scroll view don't appear to be getting press events, you may need to adjust the userInteractionEnabled property of parent views.

You can "move" any view from one view hierarchy to another by doing:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[anotherParentView addSubview:myView];
```